# NSManagedObjectContext's exeucteRequest:error: returns nil

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchrequest

The following code completes with variables res and err both equal to nil. Why is executeRequest:error: returning nil? The managed object context is not nil. This method is undocumented...

```
NSBatchUpdateRequest *request = [NSBatchUpdateRequest batchUpdateRequestWithEntityName:@"EntityName"];
        request.predicate = predicate; // assume a syntactically correct predicate
        request.propertiesToUpdate = @{@"booleanProperty" : @(YES)};
        request.resultType = NSUpdatedObjectsCountResultType;
        NSError *err;
        NSBatchUpdateResult *res = (NSBatchUpdateResult *)[managedObjectContext executeRequest:request error:&err];
```

Comment: Have you found the solution for this? I'm having the exact problem (Xcode 7.1)

Comment: My issue was that the persisted objects were not written back to SQLite by the time this batch update request executed on a different thread. So it was trying to batch update objects that did not exist yet.

Comment: Nice! I just check my code again, and it was the same problem! Slightly different that it can't save because merge conflict (because thread conflict).

Answer (score 0):

This is really not so well documented as you no doubt have found out. I made this work a while back by sending the request to the store coordinator rather than the context.

```
[persistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:request withContext:context error:&err]
```

Still, according to the documentation, a `nil` result is expected only if it is a save operation (it is not clear if the update operation is classified as a save operation). The `NSBatchUpdateResult` is not documented exhaustively.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use this and my app crash, giving NSInvalidArgumentException ( unrecognize selector [__NSCFString name]). Can you help me please? It die right after execute that code you provide (Xcode 7.1, build on iPad sim 8.4)

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with this solution. You should ask another question and include your code.